# Slow to convert Oracle 11g XMLType into Java String or Document

Tags: java, oracle, document, xmltype

After retrieving a result set from an Oracle 11g database, it takes roughly 75 seconds to convert the XMLType (this is a structured XML Storage, registered with an xsd) into either a java String or Document. I'm using Java 1.6, have the xdb.jar and xmlparserv2.jar

This xsd is <100 lines and the xml document is also <100 lines.

Sample code:

```
oracle.xdb.XMLType xml = oracle.xdb.XMLType.createXML((oracle.sql.OPAQUE)rset.getObject("XMLDATA"));
```

The other way, but still took just as long:

```
XMLType xml = (XMLType)rset.getObject("XMLDATA");
xml.getStringVal();
```

Or

```
XMLType xml = (XMLType)rset.getObject("XMLDATA");
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = xml.getDocument();
```

Either way of the above ways takes just as long.

Comment: Could you show the first few lines of your xml and xsd? Maybe there is a refernece to a dtd or schema by url that your parser tries to lookup and times out?

Comment: The interesting thing is that I have tried this with the unstructured XMLType in Oracle and it runs very quickly.

The xsd: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
 <xsd:element name="ICRXMLData" type="ICRXMLDataType" xdb:defaultTable="ICRXMLData"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="ICRXMLDataType" xdb:SQLType="ICRXMLData_T">

The xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ICRXMLData>
  <CaseInfo>
    <CaseID>1</CaseID>
  </CaseInfo>